# How to translate 钓胃口?

Tags: translation

The word 胃口 means appetite but the verb 钓 makes it tricky to translate the term literally as it wouldn't really make sense.

Just wondering if anyone has found a nice way to translate this common term in a way that also makes sense in English without deviating from the meaning of the characters too much (if that's possible).

Here are some potential candidates I thought of:

- arouse one's appetite (matches most in meaning of characters)
- pique one's interest
- leave one in suspense (matches most in meaning I think)

I would have added 'dangle a carrot in front of someone' but I think it implies something else rather than simply trying to tease someone by with holding something from them.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of 钓胃口 is to hang something in front of someone who desires it but not let him have it immediately.

Both '**tempt with a teaser**' and '**tease with a cliffhanger**' can be called 钓胃口

"leave one in suspense" is a good one,

Example: "leave the readers in suspense"  = 钓读者的胃口

~

'To tantalize' also works

> [tantalize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tantalize)

> to tease or torment by or as if by presenting something desirable to the view but continually keeping it out of reach

Example:

Teaser and cliffhanger are for tantalizing the audience - 預告和悬念都钓读者胃口的工具

Answer (score 1):

Whet your appetite (to make you want more).

Comment: Thanks for editing my post!

Answer (score 1):

WE say 吊胃口, but I assume they are the same - tantalizing one's appetite (for something).

tantalize - Excite or tease by presenting or offering something desirable, esp. when it is unobtainable.

吊胃口 - tease a person by suspending something desired by him/her.